# responsive grids with background image which is responsive

Tags: html, css

I am working on this project, the url is  grouporigin.com//clients/upload/WAHA_Capital1/index.html  If you see the bottom section in the home page, the div boxes with the background images are behaving differently than the div boxes without a background image. They are also not covering the full height. What css changes I need to do, to make the divs with the background image behave in exactly the same way, as the div boxes without a background image.

Comment: sorry, it is   http://grouporigin.com/clients/upload/WAHA_Capital1/index.html

Comment: Please add the relevant code _within_ your question and provide a [MCVE].

Comment: yaah agree please add some code

Comment: #big1,#big3{background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100%;background-position:center}#big1,#big2,#big3,#big4{width:15%;height:100%;float:left}#small1,#small2,#small3{width:8.3%;height:100%;float:left}#big5{float:right;width:15%;height:100%;background-color:#94ada5;background-color:rgba(148,173,165,.5)}#container_home1{width:100%;height:100%}#big1{background-image:url(../images/home_big1.jpg)}#big2{background-color:#595d8e}

Comment: #big3{background-image:url(../images/home_big2.jpg)}#big4{background-color:#c06867;background-color:rgba(193,103,102,.5)}#small1,#small3{background:url(../images/home_small1.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:100%}#small2{background:url(../images/home_small2.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:100%}

Comment: this the css for the divs i have used

Comment: <section id=home><div class="child child1"></div><div class="child child2"><p class=head1>Strength in<br>diversity</div><div class="child child3"><div id=container_home1><div id=big1></div><div id=small1></div><div id=big2></div><div id=big3></div><div id=small2></div><div id=big4></div><div id=small3></div><div id=big5></div></div></div></section>

Answer (score 0):

as you are not providing any html i try by inspect element.. and you make comman mistake. while using bootstrap grid system you need to wrap every element in th form of `<div class="row">` as you can see in pic the 3 div with `class name` `"form-field"` is not wrap around `row class div`

[image]

wrap these div around row like

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="form-field">..</div>
```

do this for every row and give appropriate `col-sm-* class`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not using bootstrap at all. I am doing the css with media queries myself. The html code is as below

Comment: <section id=home><div class="child child1"></div><div class="child child2"><p class=head1>Strength in<br>diversity</div><div class="child child3"><div id=container_home1><div id=big1></div><div id=small1></div><div id=big2></div><div id=big3></div><div id=small2></div><div id=big4></div><div id=small3></div><div id=big5></div></div></div></section>

Comment: The project is at the url   http://grouporigin.com/clients/upload/WAHA_Capital1/index.html

Comment: No. I am not using bootstrap at all.